# AutoLayout not working with embedded Xib file

Tags: ios, swift

I have a nib with a label in it, which is centered vertically and horizontally using Auto Layout. I declared a subclass of `UIView` and loaded the nib file in it.

I then added an `UIView` to my main view controller and assigned the new subclass to it. The problem is that the label of the nib file is not centered to the view, it doesn't follow the AutoLayout constraints.

[image]

[Download test project.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/25opq77fm39lc4h/TestXibAutoLayout.zip?dl=0) Why is this happening?

Comment: the label looks like it is centered to blue view. What else do you need ? DO you want it to be centered to self.view ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri the problem is that the blue view has a width that is exactly half of the superview size, therefore the label it's not centered and there seems to be an offset to the right.

Comment: after you load the xib, you have to change its frame manually, and make it equal to the blue view frame which is half of super view frame!

Comment: as you are loading the xib programmatically, it takes the original frame size of xib that is designed in storyboard. Make an outlet property of your custom view and change its frame after you load the xib!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri thanks. I'm trying to find a method to call on the custom view to update its frame. Perhaps `layoutIfNeeded()`?

Comment: No need to call layoutIfNeeded() if you change the frame right before you add it as subview to superview!

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you should write you custom class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        view.frame = bounds
        self.addSubview(self.view)
    }
}
```

Here's a working example:

[Testxibautolayout2.zip](http://www.filedropper.com/testxibautolayout2)

Answer (score 3):

As you are loading the xib programmatically, it takes the original frame size of xib that is designed in storyboard which is 600x600. Make an outlet property of your custom view and change its frame after you load the xib! –

In your case you have to do it like:

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var testView: UIView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.testView)
        self.testView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
        //or
        self.testView.frame=self.bounds
    }
}
```